# What's wrong with this simple HTML table accessing?

Tags: javascript, html, html-parsing

I'm using JavaScript to access the HTML table element.

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Popup page</title>
  </head>
  <body>

   <form name="F1" method="POST">
        TOTAL  : <p id="total"></p>
    PERCENTAGE : <p id="percentage"></p>
   </form>


 //This table has 9 rows and 7 columns.
 // I'd like to get the 6th column elements from 2nd row onwards.

  <table  class="collapse" >
  <tbody>
  <tr><td>S.No.</td><td>Subject Code</td><td>Subject Name </td><td>Int. Marks</td> 
  <td>Ext. Marks</td><td>Total</td><td>Credits</td><td>Result</td></tr>   
  <tr><td>1</td><td>GR11A1009</td><td>Environmental Science</td><td>23</td><td>66</td> 
  <td>89</td><td>3</td><td>P</td></tr>
  <tr><td>2</td><td>GR11A1010</td><td>Mathematics - II</td><td>22</td><td>58</td>
  <td>4</td><td>P</td></tr><td>80</td>
  <tr><td>3</td><td>GR11A1011</td><td>Engineering Chemistry</td><td>17</td><td>53</td>  
  <td>70</td><td>3</td><td>P</td></tr>  
  <tr><td>4</td><td>GR11A1012</td><td>Engineering Graphics</td><td>20</td><td>47</td>
  <td>67</td><td>3</td><td>P</td></tr>
  <tr><td>5</td><td>GR11A1013</td><td>IT Workshop</td><td>25</td><td>43</td><td>68</td>
  <td>2</td><td>P</td></tr>
  <tr><td>6</td><td>GR11A1014</td><td>Engineering Chemistry Lab</td><td>13</td>
  <td>30</td><td>43</td><td>3</td><td>P</td></tr>
  <tr><td>7</td><td>GR11A1015</td><td>English Lab</td><td>20</td><td>44</td><td>64</td>
  <td>3</td><td>P</td></tr>
  <tr><td>8</td><td>GR11A1018</td><td>Mathematics - III</td><td>20</td><td>67</td>
  <td>3</td><td>P</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>


//JavaScript starts here
<script> 

var table = document.getElementByClass("collapse");

var marks = new Array();

var total = 0,percentage;

//here is code to get all the 6th column elements fro 2nd row onwards.
 for(var i=0;i<8;i++)
   marks[i] = table.ChildNodes[0].ChildNodes[i+1].ChildNodes[5].nodeValue;

//here I'm adding all the values stored ( subject marks) and finding the grand total
 for(var i=0;i<8;i++)
  total +=marks[i];

//now, I'm calculating the percentage
 percentage = total/725;

//Below code isn't having any effect. Why is it?
document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
document.getElementById("percentage").innerHTML = percentage;

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

What is the problem with the above code ? What can I do to solve it?

### Here is the output:

[image]

Comment: You are not parsing the table. You are just accessing it in the DOM, after a browser has parsed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems with the code. In addition to the problem with `getElementByClass` (there is no such method, use `document.getElementsByClassName("collapse")[0]` instead), you are trying to access the elements in the table using `ChildNodes` (undefined). You probably meant to write `childNodes`, but you should really using `children`, since you don’t want to have to do with all the text nodes containing just whitespace. And you are accessing cells without checking that they exist; not all rows have 6th cell in your table.

There is also a spurious `</tr>` tag that confuses table parsing. Remove it.

Morever, to get the content of a `td` element, you cannot use `nodeValue`, which is defined for text nodes only. You could use `innerText`, but due to issues in browser support, the good old `innerHTML` is safer. Then you need to convert the data from string to number (otherwise adding 2 and 2 gives your 22, not 4), e.g. with the `Number` function. You may wish to add some error-checking here (and elsewhere).

```
 for(var i=0;i<8;i++)
   marks[i] = table.children[0].children[i+1].children[5].innerHTML;
 for(var i=0;i<8;i++)
   total += Number(marks[i]);
```

Comment: Thanks buddy, for all those changes .I've changed them.Still same result.How can I use 'children'.I think every row has 6th column.

Comment: The third row has a spurious end tag: ...`</tr><td>80</td>`, so the cell with “80” is parsed (at least by some browsers) as constituting a single-cell row. Remove the `</tr>` tag or move it past the last cell of the row.

Comment: The last serious error seems to be that when accessing a `td` element, you try to use its `nodeValue`, but that’s something that only text nodes have. I’ll add a note on this to my answer.

Comment: Buddy , you rock! I got it.I made all the recommendations u suggested.It finally worked man.Thanks a ton!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean document.getElementsByClassName()
change your  document.getElementByClass to document.getElementsByClassName()
And my personal suggestion for you is to use jquery for this , which may be much more efficient and easy for this purpose

In jquery you can simplify it like this
(Dont forget to add a class to your total TD)

```
    var total = 0;
    var percentage = 0;

    $(".collapse tr").each(function(e){
       var tr = $(this);
       var mark =$(this).find(".total").html(); 
       var marktst=0;
       if(!isNaN(Number(mark))) //NullChecking
       {
       marktst =Number(mark);
       }
    total +=marktst;

   });
   document.getElementById("total").innerHTML = total;
```

A fiddle is given below

http://jsfiddle.net/AmarnathRShenoy/j4hVc/5/

Comment: Thanks @Amarnath R Shenoy , I've changed Class to ClassName but no change. <p> elements are not modified.

Comment: I added the output @Amarnath R Shenoy

Comment: add type="text/javascript" to your script tag :D

Comment: Thaks @Amarnath R Shenoy for yout time.Your code dealy with JQuery , but I don't know it.I just begun with JavaScript.Anyways Thanks for ur answer.All the best!